# Converting char* to struct

Tags: c++, c, sockets

In the code [here](http://www.binarytides.com/packet-sniffer-code-c-linux/), there is a line:

```
struct iphdr * iph = (struct iphdr *)buffer;
```

in `ProcessPacket` function where `buffer` is of type `char*`. `buffer` has been given value by `recvfrom` in the main function. How is the simple string (`buffer`) converted to a structure and how is the data safely extracted?

**iphdr:**

```
struct iphdr {
    #if defined(__LITTLE_ENDIAN_BITFIELD)
        __u8    ihl:4,
                version:4;
    #elif defined (__BIG_ENDIAN_BITFIELD)
        __u8    version:4,
                ihl:4;
    #else
        #error  "Please fix <asm/byteorder.h>"
    #endif
         __u8   tos;
         __u16  tot_len;
         __u16  id;
         __u16  frag_off;
         __u8   ttl;
         __u8   protocol;
         __u16  check;
         __u32  saddr;
         __u32  daddr;
         /*The options start here. */
};
```

Comment: The data in `buffer` is *not* a string, that's the important bit to know here. Instead it's just a chunk of bytes, which happens to correspond the the structure.

Comment: If write to buffer was done in this way: `unit8_t *buffer = (uint8_t *)&yourStruct`, then going back will work ok: `yourStruct* str = (yourStruct *)buffer`. Otherwise, `memcpy` should be performed.

Comment: @Some programmer dude The `recvfrom` edits a string of data to fill the packet data in it. If it corresponds to the structure, then printing the edited string must also contain the header data, not the just the string, but this does not happen.

Comment: The data you receive is binary data, it doesn't correspond to any characters that can be printed. It is (again) ***not*** a string (in the C or C++ sense). It's like reading non-text binary data from a file, would you expect to be able to print it? Or to use the data as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to understand is that the bits on memory stay exactly the same irrespective of the cast `(struct iphdr *)`. Just that you are now saying that `buffer` is now to be treated as a pointer to `struct iphdr` instead of what it was before. You are just telling the compiler to look at the bits with a different pair of glasses and hence interpret accordingly. The compiler suddenly sees that `buffer` has become a `struct iphdr *`. And says "OK" that's all. What's important is you know exactly what `buffer` is and cast it to the proper type.

If you wanted, you could have type-casted `buffer` to `int *` (or any other pointer type) and the compiler would have said nothing. Although you would have problems later on.

Answer (score 5):

`buffer` is **not** a `string`. It is a pointer to *raw* binary data. `recvfrom` fills (in this example, see below) `buffer` with raw IP/TCP frames (aka packets). Thus, the first `sizeof(iphdr)` bytes of `buffer` is the [IP-header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_header) struct: `iphdr`. And that is exactly why the author of the blog use the snippet you presented:

```
struct iphdr * iph = (struct iphdr *)buffer;
```

If there are IP header options included then the actual size of the header is `iph->ihl*4`.

The *protocol* field (`iph->protocol`) of the header is then inspected in `ProcessPacket` (in the blog), to determine which transport protocol the packet contains.

If the transport protocol used is [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) then the TCP header (and later the data) can be extracted using (snippet from blog):

```
unsigned short iphdrlen = iph->ihl*4;
struct tcphdr *tcph = (struct tcphdr*)(buffer + iphdrlen);
```

**Raw Frames**

The author of the blog created the socket using:

```
sock_raw = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_RAW , IPPROTO_TCP);
```

- The first parameter `AF_INET` means that you want [IPv4](https://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) packet (as oppose to `AF_INET6` for [IPv6](https://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6)).
- The second parameter tells `socket` that you want the raw frames
- The third parameter (`IPPROTO_TCP`) ensures that you get TCP frames

Alternatively, if you want [UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) frames you could use:

```
 sock_raw = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_RAW , IPPROTO_UDP);
```

In case you are *greedy* and want **every** packet use (please do read up on the frame format before using this!):

```
socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
```

Comment: Outstanding explanation, but another answer was more appropriate in my question's context. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the code introduces undefined behaviour due to the following two lines that are executed in the course of your program:

```
unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char *)malloc(65536);
...
struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr*)buffer;
```

`buffer` is a pointer to a memory block reserved as `unsigned char*`, which is then casted to a pointer of type `struct iphdr`; yet `struct iphdr` very likely has different alignment restrictions than `char*`, and this is undefined behaviour (cf, for example, [this online c11 draft standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p7)):

> 6.3.2.3 Pointers
>
> (7) A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a
>   different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly
>   aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined. ...

Though it may work (which is still one of the options of UB), it can also be that the program behaves in way that you do not intend.

I'd suggest to copy the information into a correctly aligned `struct iphdr`-object instead:

```
unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char *)malloc(65536);
...
struct iphdr iphobj;
memcpy(&iphobj,buffer,sizeof(struct iphdr));
...
```

Take care of the lifetime of the object then.

Note that you tagged the code `C` and `C++`, and both languages have different rules (e.g. concerning the explicit casting of the result of `malloc`, which is required in C++ but not encouraged in C).

But concerning UB, I'm quite sure that the code introduces UB in both languages, C and C++.

Comment: does this only apply if strict-aliasing is enforced by the compiler? I've seen many C code examples where people do this but I'm a little confused as to why.